# Firefox parsing 4 digit hex color values as rgba

Tags: css, firefox

Recently observed (by accident) that Firefox (I'm using v49) is parsing 4 digit hex colors as rgba.  Reading up on the [CSS spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#numerical), I don't see any mention of support for this and was unable to find anything on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color) documenting it as a feature.  Can someone explain this please?

```css
.content {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f5f5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a" />
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is new to [Color level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-4/#hex-notation) (which is why it doesn't appear in level 3) and was indeed shipped in [Firefox 49](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/49):

> **8 digits**
> The first 6 digits are interpreted identically to the 6-digit notation. The last pair of digits, interpreted as a hexadecimal number, specifies the alpha channel of the color, where 00 represents a fully transparent color and ff represent a fully opaque color.
>
> **4 digits**
> This is a shorter variant of the 8-digit notation, "expanded" in the same way as the 3-digit notation is. The first digit, interpreted as a hexadecimal number, specifies the red channel of the color, where 0 represents the minimum value and f represents the maximum. The next three digits represent the green, blue, and alpha channels, respectively.

Comment: Yes - this is the documentation I was looking for.  Thanks for finding that.

Answer (score 2):

It's [legit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba()):

> Colors can be defined in the Red-green-blue-alpha model (RGBa) in two
>   ways:
>
> Hexadecimal notation #RRGGBBAA and #RGBA
>
> - "#", followed by eight hexadecimal characters (0-9, A-F), where the first two digits represent the red part, the second two the green
>     part, the third two the blue part and the last two the transparency.
> - "#", followed by four hexadecimal characters (0-9, A-F), where the first digit represents the red part, the second the green part, the
>     third one the blue part and the last one the transparency. The
>     four-digit RGB notation (#RGBA) and the eight-digit form (#RRGGBBAA)
>     are equal, for example, #f038 and #ff003388 represent the same color.

It's supported by Chrome 52, Firefox 49, Opera 39, and Safari 9.1

Comment: Thanks - I failed to find that link.  I have Chrome v56 and it's not supported.  Looking at the same snippet in my question the color is not rendered.

Comment: Looking at http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba it seems like it existed in Chrome 52 and 53 but was moved to the experimental features beginning in 54.